# Map the router placeholder with the URI values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing, symfony-components

I don't how to explain this so please be easy on me.

The router holds the uri variable key

```
$router = 'movie/english/{slug}/edit/(id}/{title}';
```

The URI in the browser address bar

```
$uri = 'movie/english/scorpion/edit/125/E01E05';
```

How can I write the code that will map the router placeholder variable with the URI matching value. E.g.

```
array(
    'slug' => 'scorpion',
    'id' => '125',
    'title' => 'E01E05'
);
```

Please if you understand can you redirect me to the correct resource.

Comment: I guess this is no vanilla php? else you can loop over the array and replace the values

Comment: @Keyboardninja I' am currently working on that exactly thing

Comment: You could study [symfony's routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/index.html). Which does exactly that.

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get your query string then use `explode()` to get values in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom solution for this, but you will reveal wheel every time when you will need something more, that's why my advice use the best practice:

`composer require symfony/routing`

```
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$route = new Route(
    '/movie/english/{slug}/edit/{id}/{title}',
    array('controller' => 'MyController')
);
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->add('route_name', $route);

$context = new RequestContext();
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
$parameters = $matcher->match('/movie/english/scorpion/edit/125/E01E05');

var_dump($parameters);
```

will print:

```
array (size=5)
  'controller' => string 'MyController' (length=12)
  'slug' => string 'scorpion' (length=8)
  'id' => string '125' (length=3)
  'title' => string 'E01E05' (length=6)
  '_route' => string 'route_name' (length=10)
```

I truly believe that it's the best solution, hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly, transforming `$router` to `$uri` via the array of details can be accomplished with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$router = 'movie/english/{slug}/edit/{id}/{title}';

$details = array(
    'slug' => 'scorpion',
    'id' => '125',
    'title' => 'E01E05'
);

$uri = str_replace(array('{slug}','{id}','{title}'), $details, $router);

echo $uri;
// movie/english/scorpion/edit/125/E01E05
```